# Setting a nodeValue of a DOMelement : getElementbyId returns null

Tags: php, html, dom

When running this php script :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("../counter.html");
$ele2 = $doc->getElementById ( "coupon_id" );
if($ele2){
    $ele2->nodeValue = $result["coupon_code"];
}
$response["list"]= $doc->saveHTML();
```

$ele2 is found to be null an so it does not enter to the if condition, here is my counter.html file :

```
  <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 id="coupon" class="panel-title">Coupon name 1</h3>
    </div>
<p id="coupon_id" hidden>coupon id</p>
    <div id="counter-up" class="panel-body">
      0
    </div>
  </div>
```

I already made sure the html file was loaded successfully

Comment: your code and file is correct. check again. may be your file is not loaded. and what is `$result` there?

Comment: $result contains the new values I wish to set for the selected nodes, I already checked by echo "<pre>".$doc->saveHTML()."</pre>"; and found that the file was loaded without problems

Comment: I just tested on my local wamp server it's working but not on my host server !

Comment: then you should contact to your server administrator. i think problem is your file permissions

Comment: If you are surprised about this not working as you expect it to, that means you have not read the description of `DOMDocument::getElementById` in the manual attentively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$doc->getElementById` is returning null value. You have to find out why?

using Xpath you can achieve this

```
<?php

$xml = '<div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 id="coupon" class="panel-title">Coupon name 1</h3>
    </div>

<p id="coupon_id">coupon id</p>

    <div id="counter-up" class="panel-body">
      0
    </div>
  </div>';


//create dom object  
$doc = new DOMDocument();

//load xml string
$doc->loadHTML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$result = $xpath->query("//*[@id='coupon_id']")->item(0);

$result->nodeValue = 'hello world';

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

There is an alternate two solutions are listed here this may be useful for you

```
<?php

$xml = '<div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 id="coupon" class="panel-title">Coupon name 1</h3>
    </div>

<p id="coupon_id">coupon id</p>

    <div id="counter-up" class="panel-body">
      0
    </div>
  </div>';


//create dom object  
$doc = new DOMDocument();

//load xml string
$doc->loadHTML($xml);

//create element objects
$ele2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName("p");

//process each object element
foreach($ele2 as $obj)
{
    //change thenode value
     $obj->nodeValue = 'hello';
}

//display the html
echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

Using simple XML you can achieve this like below

```
<?php 

//create object from the string
$simplxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

//overwrite the first p tag value
$simplxml->p = 'hello world';

//display the xml
echo $simplxml->asXML();

//check you object details in debug function
print_r($simplxml);
```

Comment: How do you think I can do the same using Ids, I don't have just this situation, for example the div which id is couter-up ?

Comment: 5.3 version having issues with getElementById method. So you have to use latest version in the server or you have to use simple xml library which will help you more. This is may helpful not an answer